# Get request response is not accessible

Tags: javascript, rest, api, httprequest, axios

Using Axios to get request which is returning the response. But the response is not accessible. How can I access the parameters?

```
axios.get(request)
        .then(function(response) {
            res.status(200).send(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

I expect the output

```
{"Message":"","Names":[{"Abn":"61674629751"}]}
```

but the output is

```
callback({"Message":"","Names":[{"id":"61674629751"}]})
```

Comment: is this a JSONP endpoint?

Comment: Agreed it seems to be a JSONP response rather than JSON. You can easily Google how to construct a JSONP request

Comment: Yes, the response is in JSONP. Is there any way to convert Jsonp to JSON using javascript?

Comment: No. Better to go along with it and treat it like JSONP instead. It's not particularly difficult to handle a JSONP request

Comment: parse-jsonp npm package did the job. Thanks guys.